# Get Date with Day of the Week

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I've got:

```
<%# ((DateTime)Eval("StartDate")).ToShortDateString() %>
```

What output I need:

> Saturday, 06/28/2012

What's the correct formatting string to use to get this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<%# ((DateTime)Eval("StartDate")).ToString("dddd, MM/dd/yyyy") %>
```

Link for further reference: [custom time and date formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has nicely explained this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
<%# ((DateTime)Eval("StartDate")).ToString("dddd, MM/dd/yyyy") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out `"dddd, MM/dd/yyyy"`

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on MSDN